# Difference between React Component and React Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the difference between React Component and React Element? The documentation mentions both but does not go into detail, some methods require components, other elements...

Comment: Perhaps this blog post helps to demystify elements vs components https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-element-component/

Answer (score 121):

There are *three* related kinds of thing involved here, with their own names:

- Components
- Component instances
- Elements

This is slightly surprising, since if you're used to other UI frameworks you might expect that there'd only be two kinds of thing, roughly corresponding to classes (like `Widget`) and instances (like `new Widget()`). That's not the case in React; component instances are *not* the same thing as elements, nor is there a one-to-one relationship between them. To illustrate this, consider this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('This is a component instance:', this);
  }

  render() {
    const another_element = <div>Hello, World!</div>;
    console.log('This is also an element:', another_element);
    return another_element;
  }
}

console.log('This is a component:', MyComponent)

const element = <MyComponent/>;

console.log('This is an element:', element);

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In the code above:

- `MyComponent` (the *class itself*) is a Component
- `element` is an Element. It's *not* an instance of `MyComponent`; rather, it's simply a description of the component instance to be created. It's an object with `key`, `props`, `ref` and `type` properties. Here, `key` and `ref` are `null`, `props` is an empty object, and `type` is `MyComponent`.
- An *instance* of `MyComponent` gets created (and, in the example above, logs itself from its constructor) when `element` gets rendered.
- `another_element` is also an element, and has `key`, `ref`, `props` and `type` properties just like `element` does - but this time the value of `type` is the string `"div"`.

The design reasons why React has these three distinct concepts are explored in detail in the React team's blog post [*React Components, Elements, and Instances*](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html), which I recommend reading.

Finally, it should be noted that while the official docs are rigorous about using the term "component" to refer to a function or class and "component instance" to refer to an instance, other sources do not necessarily adhere to this terminology; you should expect to see "component" used (incorrectly) to mean "component instance" when reading Stack Overflow answers or discussions on GitHub.

Comment: To sum up, Component can be used to create an Instance and when that Instance is rendered an Element is created.

Comment: Any thoughts about React Node?

Comment: How is that not one-to-one relationship between component instance and element? Are you suggesting that an element can describe multiple component instances? Or that multiple elements can describe the same component instance? Otherwise, they are by definition one-to-one related.

Comment: @Andy Multiple elements can describe the same component instance. (Not simultaneously, but over the course of that instance's lifetime. If you have a parent component that always returns `<Child/>` from its `render()` method, each time `render()` is called it's going to return a new element, but an already-existing `Child` component may be reused to realise that element.)

Comment: @Andy ... and, while it's perhaps less usual, multiple components can also be described by the same element - even simultaneously. You could store an element in a variable - say, `el = <SomeComponent>` - then embed that one element many times over inside some big JSX expression returned by a `render()` method (that is, do `<div>{el}{el}{el}{el}</div>`).

Comment: @Mark If it's not simultaneous, it's still one-to-one, just with a different "one" at a time. It's like you own an ID card, lost it, get another one, it's still one-to-one between you and your ID card because you can't own 2 valid IDs at a time. For the second "less usual" case, I'm not saying it's not possible to get out of your way to make them not one-to-one, I'm just saying for practical purposes of the tool, element and instance are meant to be one-to-one.

Comment: For all practical purposes, what is the difference between a *component* and a *description of the component instance to be created*? Yes, the former is a class or a function and the latter is an object. But the mapping is done by the system automatically - as a React programmer, I don't need to think about this in that much detail.

Comment: @JanezKuhar Some practical consequences that come to mind: 1. simply creating an element with `x = <Foo>` doesn't run the `Foo` constructor; 2. a component creating fresh elements to represent its children on each render (as most components do) doesn't mean new component instances will be created for those children; 3. reusing an element stored in a variable across renders doesn't mean you'll get the same component instance each time. So the distinction is in fact very consequential; point 2 especially is relied upon by most React apps even if their authors aren't conscious of it!

Comment: @MarkAmery I'm just saying it is not practical to make this distinction when explaining React to someone. Consider the following snippet from a documentation page: [State and Lifecycle | The Data Flows Down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down) *"A component may choose to pass its state down as props to its child components: `<FormattedDate date={this.state.date} />`"* You can't say in such a case that you are talking about a "description of the component instance to be created".

Comment: `console.log('What am I?', MyComponent());` :-)

Comment: This answer is from 2017, when most components were class components. Now in 2022, when most components are functions, we have only components and elements. A functional component does not have instances.

Answer (score 36):

To further elaborate on the answer, a React Element does not have any methods and nothing on the prototype. This also makes them fast.

"A ReactElement is a light, stateless, immutable, virtual representation of a DOM Element" - [Glossary of React Terms](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#react-elements)

A react component `render()` function returns a DOM tree of react elements behind the scenes (This is the virtual DOM btw). There is some complex mapping and diff logic involved, but basically these React elements map to the DOM elements.

You can also create a Element directly `React.createElement(arg)` where arg can be a html tag name, or a React Component class.

Comment: I am not sure that the `ReactElement` is the VDOM itself... but I am not much of an expert on this topic, this is just a hunch. In my understanding a react `Element` still needs to be rendered to a VDOM which is then diffed with the "previous" VDOM.

I think `user6445533`'s answer says the same. Right ? I am no expert but somehow common sense tells me that this is the only meaningful interpretation, after a bit of thinking... but my intuition might be wrong.

Comment: This answer is from a long time ago (2015) and the VDOM structure and its access would have changed. I'll have to update it I think, but I haven't worked with React since then, so I'll have to research first.
If anyone wants to moderate this or put in comments, I'd be most happy! :)

Answer (score 34):

## React Elements vs React Components

### React Elements

- A React Element is what gets returned from components. It’s an object that virtually describes the DOM nodes that a component represents.
- With a function component, this element is the object that the function returns.
- With a class component, the element is the object that the component’s render function returns. R
- React elements are not what we see in the browser. They are just objects in memory and we can’t change anything about them.
- React elements can have other `type` properties other than native HTML elements.

We know the following:

- A react element describes what we want to see on the screen.

A more complex way of saying that is:

- A React element is an object representation of a DOM node.

_It's important to make this distinction here because the element is not the actual thing we see on the screen, rather the object representation is what is rendered.

#### React is good with this in these ways:

- React can create and destroy these element without much overhead. The JS objects are lightweight and low-cost.
- React can diff an object with the previous object representation to see what has changed.
- React can update the actual DOM specifically where the changes it detected occurred. This has some performance upsides.

We can create an object representation of a DOM node (aka React element) using the `createElement` method.

```
const element = React.createElement(
  'div',
  {id: 'login-btn'},
  'Login'
  )
```

Here `createElement` takes in three arguments

1. The tag name (eg. div, span, etc)
2. Any attribuites we want the element to have
3. The contents of the children of the element (eg. the text that reads `Login`)

The `createElement` invocation returns an object

```
{
  type: 'div',
  props: {
    children: 'Login',
    id: 'login-btn'
  }
}
```

When this is rendered to the DOM (using `ReactDOM.render`), we'll have a new DOM node that looks like this:

```
<div id='login-btn'>Login</div>
```

#### Huzzah!

[image: Huzzah]

> Generally React is taught from a components-first approach, however understanding elements-first makes for a smooth transition to components.

### React Components

> A component is a function or a Class which optionally accepts input and returns a React element.

- A React Component is a template. A blueprint. A global definition. This can be either a function or a class (with a render function).
- If react sees a class or a function as the first argument, it will check to see what element it renders, given the corresponding props and will continue to do this until there are no more `createElement` invocations which have a class or a function as their first argument.
- When React sees an element with a function or class type, it will consult with that component to know which element it should return, given the corresponding props.
- At the end of this processes, React will have a full object representation of the DOM tree. This whole process is called reconciliation in React and is triggered each time `setState` or `ReactDOM.render` is called.

Class-Based Components

> Class syntax is one of the most common ways to define a React component. While more verbose than the functional syntax, it offers more control in the form of lifecycle hooks.

- We can render many instances of the same component.
- The instance is the "this" keyword that is used inside the class-based component.
- Is not created manually and is somewhere inside React's memory.

*Create a class component*

```
// MyComponent.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>This is my component.</div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

*Use it in any other component*

```
// MyOtherComponent.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

class MyOtherComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>This is my other component.</div>
        <MyComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyOtherComponent;
```

*Use props*

```
<MyComponent myProp="This is passed as a prop." />
```

*Props can be accessed with `this.props`*

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const {myProp} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>{myProp}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

*Using state*

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const {myState} = this.state || {};
    const message = `The current state is ${myState}.`;
    return (
      <div>{message}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

*Using lifecycle hooks*

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  // Executes after the component is rendered for the first time
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({myState: 'Florida'});
  }

  render() {
    const {myState} = this.state || {};
    const message = `The current state is ${myState}.`;
    return (
      <div>{message}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Function-Based Components

- Do not have instances.
- Can be rendered multiple times but React does not associate a local instance with each render.
- React uses the invocation of the function to determine what DOM element to render for the function.

*With `createElement`*

```
function Button ({ addFriend }) {
  return React.createElement(
    "button",
    { onClick: addFriend },
    "Add Friend"
  )
}

function User({ name, addFriend }) {
  return React.createElement(
    "div",
    null,
    React.createElement(
      "p",
      null,
      name
    ),
    React.createElement(Button, { addFriend })
  )
}
```

*With what `createElement` returns*

```
function Button ({ addFriend }) {
  return {
    type: 'button',
    props: {
      onClick: addFriend,
      children: 'Add Friend'
    }
  }
}

function User ({ name, addFriend }) {
  return {
    type: 'div',
    props: {
      children: [
        {
          type: 'p',
          props: {
            children: name
          }
        },
        {
          type: Button,
          props: {
            addFriend
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here we have a `Button` component which accepts an `onLogin` input and returns a React element.

- The `Button` component receives an `onLogin` method as its property.
- To pass that along to our object representation of the DOM, we'll pass it along as the second argument to createElement, just as we did with the `id` attribute.

Comment: wow. your answer is great.

Answer (score 28):

## React Elements

A React Element is just a plain old JavaScript `Object` without own methods. It has essentially four properties:

- `type`, a `String` representing an HTML tag or a reference referring to a React Component
- `key`, a `String` to uniquely identify an React Element
- `ref`, a reference to access either the underlying DOM node or React Component Instance)
- `props` (properties `Object`)

A React Element is not an instance of a React Component. It is just a simplified "description" of how the React Component Instance (or depending on the `type` an HTML tag) to be created should look like.

A React Element that describes a React Component doesn't know to which DOM node it is eventually rendered - this association is abstracted and will be resolved while rendering.

React Elements may contain child elements and thus are capable of forming element trees, which represent the Virtual DOM tree.

## React Components and React Component Instances

A custom React Component is either created by `React.createClass` or by extending `React.Component` (ES2015). If a React Component is instantiated it expects a `props` `Object` and returns an instance, which is referred to as a React Component Instance.

A React Component can contain state and has access to the React Lifecycle methods. It must have at least a `render` method, which returns a React Element(-tree) when invoked. Please note that you never construct React Component Instances yourself but let React create it for you.

Comment: This and Mark's answer are the "GOOD" ones... they clarify the point that React Element IS NOT VDOM ! ! ! :) :) ... It is a "lifting" - sort of like an abstract syntax tree of a programming language. Or a Monad. To put it simply.

Answer (score 24):

`React Element` - It is a simple object that describes a DOM node and its attributes or properties you can say. It is an immutable description object and you can not apply any methods on it.

Eg -

```
<button class="blue"></button>
```

`React Component` - It is a function or class that accepts an input and returns a React element. It has to keep references to its DOM nodes and to the instances of the child components.

```
const SignIn = () => (
  <div>
   <p>Sign In</p>
   <button>Continue</button>
   <button color='blue'>Cancel</button>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 11):

A component is a factory for creating elements.

Answer (score 3):

An **element** is a plain object describing what you want to appear on the screen in terms of the DOM nodes or other components. Elements can contain other elements in their props. Creating a React element is cheap. Once an element is created, it is never mutated. The object representation of React element would be as follows,

```
const element = React.createElement(
  'div',
  {id: 'login-btn'},
  'Login'
)
```

The above createElement returns as object as below,

```
{
  type: 'div',
  props: {
    children: 'Login',
    id: 'login-btn'
  }
}
```

And finally it renders to the DOM using ReactDOM.render as below,

```
<div id='login-btn'>Login</div>
```

Whereas a **component** can be declared in several different ways. It can be a class with a render() method. Alternatively, in simple cases, it can be defined as a function. In either case, it takes props as an input, and returns an element tree as the output. JSX transpiled as createElement at the end.

```
function Button ({ onLogin }) {
  return React.createElement(
    'div',
    {id: 'login-btn', onClick: onLogin},
    'Login'
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can simplify this question with few examples.

*Defining Box:*

```
function Box() {
   return (
      // few code 
   )
}
```

if we do `console.log(Box)` we say that we are logging a **React Component** to the console.

And if we do `console.log(<Box />)` we say that we are logging a **React Element** to the console, and same thing with the following code `console.log(<Box>...<Box />)`.

*Summary:*

- `Box` : **React Component.**
- `<Box />` or `<Box>...</Box>` : **React Element.**

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take :

`Element` is the thing that describes how to construct the VDOM. It's basically a "frozen" version of the corresponding `Component Instance`.

If everything would be `functional component` then there would be no need for an extra react `Element`. The `functional component` hierarchy could produce the VDOM tree directly.

A react `Component Instance` hierarchy (`tree`) is a "factory", and that factory is parametrized by the props which are fed to the root react `Component Instance` and by all the state "stored" anywhere in the `Component Instance` tree.

So the react `Element` is basically an "abstract syntax tree" which gets compiled into the actual VDOM.

So why not generate the VDOM directly by using the react `Component Instances` ? This is the real question here.

At the first glance I don't see why it would not be possible to do so. So most likely the answer is that it's a question of performance.

The react `Element` is one layer of abstraction between the VDOM and the `Component Instance`, why this abstraction is needed is not entirely clear to me, most likely it allows optimizations. For example the `Element` tree does not get rendered completely if some lifecycle method on the `Component Instance` says that there is no need to render that subtree.

Now, in this case, the logic which handles this optimization "needs" this extra layer of indirection - because the information needs to be stored somewhere that some part of the VDOM should not be compared with the new VDOM, even more, maybe the new VDOM should not be even calculated at all. So using an extra layer of indirection makes the rendering logic simpler and leads to a cleaner, more maintainable implementation - I imagine.

This concept in Haskell is called "[lifting](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lifting)" :

For example monads in Haskell are perfect examples of such liftings.

A monad is sort of a description of a computation that can be stored as a value, like `42`. Similarly, react `Elements` are elments of a description on how to compute the "new" VDOM. If somebody wants to compute it.

This talk describes this concept of an "extra" indirection with some simple [examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqmsQeSzMdw) :

In other words : premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Or :[Fundamental theorem of software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering)

> The fundamental theorem of software engineering (FTSE) is a term
>   originated by Andrew Koenig to describe a remark by Butler Lampson[1](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lifting)
>   attributed to the late David J. Wheeler:[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqmsQeSzMdw)
>
> We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection.

So, in my understanding react `Elements` are an implementation detail to handle complexity gracefully and allow some optimization (performance). I don't see why one could not get rid of this extra indirection - in principle - react would still work "just as well" - but it might be super slow, implementing and maintaining the react "engine" itself would be probably a nightmare.

Please correct me if I am missing here something.

**Quoting an IMPORTANT part of user6445533's answer :**

> `type`, a String representing an HTML tag or a reference referring to a
>   React Component

THIS IS THE KEY ^^^^

Element IS NOT VDOM.

Answer (score -1):

A `React Element` is what you would consider to be a basic html(dom to be precise) element. It is just a way of creating element without using the much controversial jsx format.

A `React Component` is what you can consider as an object. It has its methods, supports `React lifecycles` and is generally unreusable (at least haven't found any reuse yet, welcome to examples). It necessarily needs to have a render function.

A `React Class` is what you call a class. Functionality wise `React Class` and `React Component` are same. Only syntax is the real change, as `React Component` is based on `ES6 syntax`. Another major change is the default binding of functions to this is no longer supported unless using arrow functions. `Mixins` also are no longer supported as of `ES6`.

Answer (score -1):

React components are mutable while elements are not

Answer (score -2):

Elements are thunks.

React lets you define UIs as pure functions defined on application state.  It could implement this by computing the entire UI during each state change, but this would be expensive.  Elements are computational descriptions (thunks), and if they don't change, and you're using `PureComponent`s, React won't bother recomputing that subtree.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.