# where is the documentation for using hidden = {true} in a react component

Tags: reactjs

When trying to hide an input tag in regular html you can use the following:

```
<input hidden />
```

and when you want to show the tag we use:

```
<input />
```

Apparently in the return portion of a react component you can do the following to hide an element:

```
<input hidden={true} />
```

I can't find any documentation for this.  Could someone direct me to a source?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you need the docs? Is something not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any standard or custom DOM attributes are fully supported according to the docs, just camel case them and react will put the corresponding attribute in the actual dom.
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

you may also find it helpful to read the intro to JSX since there may be confusion there.
https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Lastly just being nit picky `<inpupt />` is a react element not a react component.
[Difference between React Component and React Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30971395/difference-between-react-component-and-react-element)