# React.CloneElement returning an object instead of function

Tags: reactjs, components, clone, element

I am having a hard time understanding the behaviour of `React.cloneElement()` function

I have my Component Structure something like this

A.js

```
export default class A extends React.Component {
     render() {
         return (<h1>{ this.props.message }</h1>)
     }
 }
```

B.js

```
import A from "./A"

const newComponent = React.cloneElement(A,{
    message: "Hello World"
})

export default newComponent
```

C.js

```
import B from "./B"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom"

// To Be very precise
 export default class C extends React.Component {
     render() {
         return (
             <Router>
                <Route path="/" component={B}  />
            </Router>
         )
     }
 }
```

But I get this Error

*Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.*

but When I pass Component `A` directly into the `Route` component, it renders fine.

When I `console.log` Component `A` inside the render function of Component `C`, I get a function but 
When I `console.log` Component `B` inside the render function of Component `C`, I get a object

What am I missing?

Comment: why do you want to use `cloneElement`?

Comment: @SaeidAlidadi Because I want to pass props from `Component B` to `Component A`... say it somewhat requirement of my project.

Comment: I think you should use `HOC` for this purpose

Comment: @SaeidAlidadi So you are suggesting me to make `Component B` a _HOC_

Comment: So what does `CloneElement` do exactly? I have seen examples of using the function to clone `children` of React Components. @SaeidAlidadi

Comment: No, use `A` as a `HOC`. If you need to have `A` as a factory for your components which will add some behaviors it would be better to create `A` as `HOC`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159832/discussion-between-saeid-alidadi-and-besrabasant).

Comment: Yeah, I understand your point, using a HOC will solve my problem. But I wanted to know what does `React.cloneElement` do exactly? @SaeidAlidadi

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First you need to understand the [difference between `React component` and `React element`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939845/7232300).Both are actually different.

To be specific in `jsx`, in your case, `A` is a react `component` and `<A />` is a react `element`. If you look at the `React.cloneElement` docs, then it expect an `element` as a first argument, but here you are passing a `component`. So first change you need to do is to pass an element to `React.cloneElement` like this

```
const newComponent = React.cloneElement(<A />,{
    message: "Hello World"
})
```

The second thing is that the `Route` component expects a `react component` as `component prop`, but `React.cloneElement` returns a `react element` instead of component (that means `newComponent` is an element, not component). Therefore you cannot just simply export `newComponent` from the `B.js` file. You have to export a `component` instead. For that you can create a `class component`/`stateless component`. So your `B.js` should look something like this

```
// B.js
import A from "./A"

const newComponent = React.cloneElement(<A />, {
  message: "Hello World"
})

export default class B extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>{newComponent}</div>)
  }
}
```

By the way, you don't even need `cloneElement` here in your case. You can simply return a component from `B.js` which render `A`. This is just for understanding purpose.

Comment: Understood. Very well explained.