# When does React create a new component instance?

Tags: reactjs, constructor

I have a question about the constructor in React

Look at a example at https://codesandbox.io/s/lpr147kmyl

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class SimpleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: props.number,
    }
    console.log('constructor', this.state.number)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.number}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showFirstComponent: true,
    }

    setInterval(() => (
      this.setState(previousState => (
        { showFirstComponent: !previousState.showFirstComponent }
      ))
    ), 1000);
  }
  render(){
    let c1 = <SimpleComponent number="1" />
    let c2 = <SimpleComponent number="2" />
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>
          {this.state.showFirstComponent ? c1 : c2}
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I checked the console log and saw only one log message.
I thought there should be two log messages there as I create two instances of SimpleComponent :

```
let c1 = <SimpleComponent number="1" />
let c2 = <SimpleComponent number="2" />
```

My question is:

**When does React create new a component instance and calls the component's constructor?**

Thanks,

Comment: Looking at your example, it looks like it's when the component is rendered, e.g. the result of the ternary operator (which is only 1 component).

Answer (score 4):

According to [the doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor), `constructor` is only called before a component is mounted. If you add two more React Lifecycle functions to your code example: `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`, you'll see that the component only mounted once in the entire process, regardless of the times the state changes. If you then add `shouldComponentUpdate` to the component, you'll see that there is only one instance of `SimpleComponent` and the upper-level state change is shown as props change on `SimpleComponent`.

The reason why you don't see two instances mounting and unmounting here is that variables `c1` and `c2` are *not* instances of `SimpleComponent` as commonly and conveniently assumed. Instead, they are [*ReactElement*](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#react-elements), which is a *description* of the component instance.

> The primary type in React is the ReactElement. It has four properties: type, props, key and ref. It has no methods and nothing on the prototype.
>
> [React (Virtual) DOM Terminology](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/fcb1b6ab493b0c77d589)

Only when the element gets rendered, an instance of the component gets created and `constructor` and the Lifecycle functions get called at their respective time points.

So then why, as in your example, the element `c2` never gets to be used to create a component? This goes back to how React decides when and what to update at a certain time (you can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#component-elements-of-the-same-type):

> When a component updates, the instance stays the same, so that state is maintained across renders.

In your example, when the `App` component renders `c2` instead of `c1`, React sees that the new component element is the same as the old one so it reuses the component(i.e. only a single instance exists) and updates the props/states accordingly.

Here are some more readings that I find useful to understand this problem:
https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/birth_mounting_indepth.html

Mark Amery's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30971395/difference-between-react-component-and-react-element/31069757#31069757) is also very helpful.

Comment: I updated the example, added componentDidMountand componentWillUnmount.

The componentWillUnmount does NOT get called.

I thought that React will unmount C1 and then mount C2 instance.
But it does not.

Please see the example https://codesandbox.io/s/lpr147kmyl

Comment: @Trung I updated the post and hopefully explained why there aren't two instances (`c1` and `c2`) as you may think. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 4):

If someone has landed here for **react-native**. 
Assigning different `keys` for different instances will create new instances instead of reusing the same instance.

```
   <MyComponent
       key={this.state.uniqueInstanceKey}
       myData={this.state.myData}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ternary is checking the state for `showFirstComponent` and rendering only one.

```
{this.state.showFirstComponent ? c1 : c2}
```

If you remove that all together, and just do

```
<SimpleComponent number="1" />
<SimpleComponent number="2" />
```

You'll get two logs. To further answer the question, `constructor` is called when the component is mounted, so usually once, unless you're dynamically mounting stuff. To get back at your ternary:

```
{this.state.showFirstComponent ? c1 : c2}
```

If you were to toggle `this.state.showFirstComponent` with a button lets say:

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({ 
    showFirstComponent: !this.state.showFirstComponent
})> 
  Toggle c1/c2 
</button>
```

Every time you hit this button, component will be unmounted, and another one mounted, so you'll get a console log. Here's the order of [react lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) between mount and unmount. However, if you do anything else, eg change the props passed, change the internal component state of `<SimpleComponent />`, it will **NOT** unmount, but rather, update, which calls the render method, and not the constructor. I suggest adding a `console.log` for some lifecycle methods in your `<SimpleComponent />` and trying to trigger them, to better understand the component lifecycle. Or [read an article about it](https://blog.pusher.com/beginners-guide-react-component-lifecycle/).

Comment: I updated https://codesandbox.io/s/lpr147kmyl

There is ONE log message only.
I am not sure what's wrong with this example

Comment: Nothing, you're assigning them to to variables ONCE, and calling them as you need them. If you were to do something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/n9nmp7n7jj that would invoke the constructor ever time. Your way, you assign them to variables once, and then basically showing them as you need them, but the construction, and even the render in your case, is called only once, when you do `let c1 = ...`.

Comment: You can also enforce two separate components using `key`.