# Return a React Component From a Function and Give it Props

Tags: reactjs

I have the following method that returns a `Component`

```
const getChildComponent = ({ type }) => {
  let childComponent = null
  switch (type) {
    case 'component_1':
      childComponent = <SomeComponent />
      break;
  }
  return { childComponent }
}

export default getChildComponent
```

I call the above method from a separate component below

```
export default class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { component } = getChildComponent({ type })
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          {childComponent} // How to pass props here?
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible to pass props from `ParentComponent` to the `childComponent` (without having to pass it through the `getChildComponent()` method)?

Comment: Eh...Pass them alongside with type?

Comment: @IndrajeetLatthe I considered that, but this may have to happen between many child components and I'm trying to avoid my app playing property football

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return [the component, not the element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939845/179125). In other words, return `SomeComponent`, not `<SomeComponent/>`:

```jsx
const getChildComponent = ({ type }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'component_1':
      return SomeComponent;
  }
}

export default class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const ChildComponent = getChildComponent({ type });
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <ChildComponent {...props}/>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your `getChildComponent` function returns a React element and not an actual component, you should be able to pass custom props to the child component by using [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement).

Here is an example using the code sample you provided.

```
export default class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { component } = getChildComponent({ type })
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          {React.cloneElement(component, { propA: "foobar" })} // pass props to second argument
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```