# React component type in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the correct way to describe the type of a react component in TypeScript?
Say we have a function which returns a react component.
The function:

```
const getTabContent: () => ReactElement = () => {
  switch (tab) {
    case 1:
      return <Images images={images} onSelect={onSelect}/>;
    default:
      return <Search onSelect={onSelect}/>;
  }
};
```

Here I describe the returning type as **ReactElement**, but I'm wondering whether it's correct or I should describe it as **ReactComponentElement** or even somehow completely differently?
Also those both types are generics and how to fully describe them if one of them is correct?

UPD ReactElement seems to fit here, because, for example, FC (FunctionComponent) returns it

Comment: `React.Component`?

Comment: Thank you @MoshFeu but it doesn't fit. Compiler gets confused

Comment: _"Say we have a function which returns a react component..."_: Your function does **not** return a React _component_, but a React **_element_**. See [difference-between-react-component-and-react-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30971395/difference-between-react-component-and-react-element)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The correct type for a functional component is `React.FunctionComponent` or `React.FC` which is a shortcut alias for it

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

const getTabContent: FC = () => {
  switch (tab) {
    case 1:
      return <Images images={images} onSelect={onSelect}/>;
    default:
      return <Search onSelect={onSelect}/>;
  }
};
```

The `FC` type simply add the `children` property to the `props` argument of the functional component so you can access it:

```
const SomeComponent: FC = ({ children }) => (
  <div className="hello">{children}</div>
);
```

`FC` is a generic type so you can "add" props to your component:

```
interface SomeComponentProps {
  foo: string;
}

const SomeComponent: FC<SomeComponentProps> = ({ children, foo }) => (
  <div className={`Hello ${foo}`}>{children}</div>
);
```

**Edit: React 18 update**

Since React 18, `FC` doesn't add the `children` prop implicitly and offers an explicit way to do so with the `PropsWithChildren` generix type

Example:

```
type SomeComponentProps = { a: string };

const SomeComponent: FC<SomeComponentProps> = ({ a }) => <div>{a}</div>;

// This will fail when using the following expression
<SomeComponent>Hey I'm a child</SomeComponent>
```

Usage with children:

```
type ComponentWithChildrenProps = PropsWithChildren<{ a: string }>;

const ComponentWithChildrenProps: FC<ComponentWithChildrenProps> = ({
  a,
  children
}) => <div>{a} and {children}</div>
```

This allows to have a `children` prop a bit stricter. e.g.

```
type StrictCompProps = { children: string };

const StrictComp: FC<StrictCompProps> = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;

// This will fail
<StrictComp><span>hey</span></StrictComp>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `<Images />` is functional component?

Comment: It isn't, `getTabContent` is. `<Images />` is the return value of said functional component

Comment: Thank you @3Dos. But if I rewrite Image and Search to class components, I should change the type here and everywhere where these components are mentioned?

Comment: I think you don't get it. The functional component here is `getTabContent` and as long as it returns JSX values or null, it will be fine. In fact, the FC type here is not necessary as type inference will be enough. The `FC` type will allow you to use the `children` prop though but some devs like to always type with FC so each component is already typed.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it a bit clearer about how to use React an TS together

Comment: @3Dos I noticed FC returns ReactElement, so your and my approaches seems to be correct. Thnx

Comment: @Gena it sure is :) `FC` seems a bit safer though as it comes from the React lib and would be updated with it when you update your packages. It's also easier to use than writing the entire signature of the component. Happy coding ;)

Comment: I don't know if it was changed in a more recent version or not, but the full name is `React.FunctionComponent` and not `React.FunctionalComponent`.

Comment: @ivarni thank you! I updated my answer with the correct full name.

Comment: ok what is the type for component in a common it is maybe a function component or class component what is the type for this case

Comment: Please note that the use of the `React.FC` type has [some limitations and is nowadays discouraged](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react/blob/main/README.md#function-components)

Comment: Worth mentioning that there's no advantage to typing your component definition explicitly. You can leave out the type and typescript is going to treat it the same in all cases because it can just infer the type.

Answer (score 51):

If you want to use FunctionComponent with class Component, 
Then use `React.ComponentType`

Answer (score 14):

Considering this built-in definition in React:

```
type PropsWithChildren<P> = P & {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}
```

I am using `React.ReactNode`. It is defined as

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

Answer (score 4):

TypeScript comes with powerful type inference. Just use it in most places. Only top-level components required fine-grained interfaces.

[For example, here resulting type will be computed as JSX.Element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=6&jsx=2&ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdBArgHb7AQtwCSIyA5lgAUyGDCioAXJiowAdL34AJACoBZADIBBMVGAAjJjCyoAPMhYBPAHwBKOAG86cOJRhMoXU6H6O5-0XFUAF84AHpremCGZjYYDi4AZRwoXAALIQc4TmSAGyx8OGDpLJysfPxpISwAN2lsPHlEyxYYNKx43ABRGqxW+wBeazgaiGAAEyL7Jxc3Dy9x4BrwyLpoulxOVHhBGBVkfQBhTmNWuAG4TLgYA4AabJY8gvhix2uD6RYmEH0sKHuyhUYFVavVZHJmq12p0en0YINhqMJlNzsMZnBUAB3YAwdKXG76abOFxwXBoLBwACMkmJJNcHXmcFMvAEFNQqQGACJKQAmADMnIi9Dp4ywBGQTFywNpJLmniZyWQqTSDye+AGDkBz2CQuJ0WCNCAA)

```
const getTabContent = ({ tab, onSelect }: { tab: number, onSelect: (ev: React.SyntheticEvent) => void }) => {
  switch (tab) {
    case 1:
      return <Image src="123"/>;
    default:
      return <Search onSelect={onSelect}/>;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`React.ReactNode` is the correct way to define a React element type.

Answer (score 3):

The best option would be `ComponentType`. If you are strict about the functional component, You can make use of `FC`. In some cases, You might want both class component type and functional component type support. (i.e. Defining a prop type where the prop is expecting a component, either functional or class).

The recommended way is to use `ComponentType` in the type definition (i.e. ProopTypes) and `FC` when you want to define return type etc.

FYI, Here is the definition of `ComponentType`, `FC` in typescript

```
type ComponentType<P = {}> = ComponentClass<P> | FunctionComponent<P>;
type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy sample of defining a component with type and using it in a different place:

step 1: define your component like this:

```
import React from "react";

const HomePage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home Page</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

step 2: define an interface in order to describe type of functional component:

```
export interface IRouteDto {
    id: number,
    path: string,
    faTitle: string
    element: React.FC,
}
```

step 3: use your interface easily:

```
export const routes: IRouteDto[] = [
    {id: 1, path:"/", faTitle: "خانه", element:HomePage}
    {id: 2, path:"/about", faTitle: "درباره ما", element:AboutPage},
    {id: 3, path:"/contact-us", faTitle: "تماس با ما", element:ContactUsPage},
]
```