# Why "he" does not write React.FC on each function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I learn typescript, and I dont understand why he write in the first Function React.FC and in other function he does not write "React.FC". Why?

exp:

```
...
const Login: React.FC<Props> = ({ signIn }) => {

 const Add = (id: number) => {
   ...
  };

 return (
  <div>
   <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
)
};
```

Why I dont write React.FC in Add function ?

Comment: How mysterious. Who is "he"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining with Typescript I actually use `FC` only if I want to pass and extract `children` from props because it is the best way to type them. If we use your example:

Without children it can be like:

```js
interface Props {
  signIn: string;
}

const Login = ({ signIn }: Props) => {
```

With children you can still do it the same way:

```js
interface Props {
  signIn: string;
  children: React.ReactNode; //or something similar, there are few options
}

const Login = ({ signIn, children }: Props) => {
```

or you can use `FC` here and skip children in your `Props` interface:

```js
interface Props {
  signIn: string;
}

const Login: React.FC<Props> = ({ signIn, children }) => {
```

Comment: This is no longer true: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56947727. And indeed the FC usage is actually now slightly discouraged: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177

Answer (score 4):

`React.FC` is (and is only) used to enforce the types for a React functional component - a function that takes in props (a single argument, which is an object) and returns a `JSX.Element`.

`Add` is not a React component, but a plain function. There's no information on how it's used, but because its argument is `(id: number)`, it's clearly not a component - so it shouldn't be typed as `React.FC`.

(You don't even need `React.FC` on components anyway - it's just a convention that some prefer)