# React, using Hooks to create component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use a hook to create a textbox that provides the value state as part of the hook.

However, I am not quite successful, as the textbox keeps losing focus whenever I tried to type.

This probably makes more sense if I show what I am doing.

Please see this Codepen for a quick demo. (https://codepen.io/david_yau/pen/RwWVoKz?editors=1111)

**Detail explaination**

```
// My first attempt
// App.jsx, the App
const App = () => {
  const [text, TextBox] = useTextBox();

  return (
    <div>
      <TextBox />
      <p>
        text: {text}
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}

// useTextBox.jsx
const useTextBox = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  }

  const TextBox = () => {
    return (
      <input type="text" value={text} onChange={onChange} />
    )
  };

  return [text, TextBox];
}
```

This way won't work because each time I typed in the textbox, the focus will be lost.

However, if I change the implementation to the following it will work.

The difference between this implementation is that the one above is rendering a new TextBox with `<TextBox />`. While the bottom one is using a rendered Textbox instead like `{TextBox}`.

```
// App.jsx
const App = () => {
  const [text, TextBox] = useTextBoxOne();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> This one work </h1>
      {TextBox}
      <p>
        text: {text}
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}

// useTextBox.jsx
const useTextBox = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  }

  const TextBox = (
      <input type="text" value={text} onChange={onChange} />
    );

  return [text, TextBox];
}
```

If it helps at all, I got this idea from this course: https://frontendmasters.com/courses/complete-react-v5/, around the "Custom Hook" session.

Just to reiterate the question since this is quite a long post. I am wondering why does the first approach does not work because it keeps losing focus, while the second one does.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry let me edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `const TextBox = () => <input />` will create a different React component every time `useTextBoxTwo()` is called, while `const TextBox = <input />` is just a React element, rendered in the same Component (in `App`).

In the current implementation, when the element inside a component changes, ReactDOM checks whether it has the same element name (e.g. "input") and doesn't have a different `key` - when true, it re-uses the same DOM element, e.g. following 2 React-elements will reuse the same DOM-element (not losing focus):

```
{condition ? <input value="a" /> : <input value="b" />}
```

But 2 different React Components will trigger unmounting of the old one, removing it from DOM, and mounting of the new one, creating a new DOM element (=> losing focus).

---

So, don't create components inside custom hooks, create custom components that use hooks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I think I kind of get the picture. But for useTextBoxTwo(), isn't the new <TextBox /> a <input /> at the end of the day? I tried digging around for relevant information but don't have any luck. Do you have an example, or some documentation that can demonstrated what happened? Thank you so much again.

Comment: check [Difference between React Component and React Element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939845/1176601).. or React Dev Tools in your browser

Comment: hi @Aprillion, thank you for your resources. I think I have a better understanding of it now. So in both useTexBoxOne and useTextBoxTwo, they are both returning a new "item", but one is a new element, and the other is a new component. And when rendering in React, a new element will not necessary trigger a recreate of a new DOM-object, thus keeping the focus. However, a new component will always trigger a unmount + mount action, thus losing focus. Am I correct?

Comment: As a side question, what is your opinion on returning element in hook?

Comment: not sure about the "always" part - you would have to check whether it's part of specification or just an implementation detail of ReactDOM (=> it could be different in React Native or Enzyme). Returning elements should be always fine, it's just a normal JS value like `"hello"` or `{data}` or `<b>hello</b>`