# Can I pass a component to child component like this? react,styled-component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I can pass a styled-component(`Text` component) like

```
export const Text = styled.span`
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
`;

Text.displayName = 'Text';


const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Child Text={Text} />
    </>
  );
};
```

but now like this

```
  <Child Text={<Text />} />
```

I get an error: `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Is there a way to pass `Text` component like this `<Child Text={<Text />} />`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between React Component and React Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30971395/difference-between-react-component-and-react-element)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to render it like this:

```
function Child({ Text }) {
  return (
    <>{Text}</>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, in your example "Text" is not a react component but a mere object. A react component is declared as a function. For example:

```
const regularObject = {"text": "I am just an object"};

const MyComponent= (props) => {
  return <p>I am a component that uses props</p>;
  // Do something with the props...
};

const SubComponent= () => {
  return <p>I am a Subcomponent</p>;
};

const App = () => {
  return <MyComponent props={<SubComponent />} />; // OR props={regularObject}
  
};

// The following will NOT work, as it is not a component:
const App = () => {
  return <MyComponent props={<regularObject />} />;
};
```