# How and when does React.cloneElement() make use of the cloned component's "constructor"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-children, clone-element

Recently I have been working my way through the [Advanced React section](https://www.coursera.org/learn/advanced-react?specialization=meta-front-end-developer) of Coursera's [Meta Front-End Developer Professional Certificate](https://www.coursera.org/professional-certificates/meta-front-end-developer), and at some point we are tasked with creating a radio button list in the following manner:

###### src/App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { RadioGroup, RadioOption } from "./Radio";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>How did you hear about Little Lemon?</h2>
      <RadioGroup onChange={setSelected} selected={selected}>
        <RadioOption value="social_media">Social Media</RadioOption>
        <RadioOption value="friends">Friends</RadioOption>
        <RadioOption value="advertising">Advertising</RadioOption>
        <RadioOption value="other">Other</RadioOption>
      </RadioGroup>
      <button disabled={!selected}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

###### src/Radio/index.js

```
import * as React from "react";

export const RadioGroup = ({ onChange, selected, children }) => { 
 const RadioOptions = React.Children.map(children, (child) => { 
   return React.cloneElement(child, { 
     onChange, 
     checked: child.props.value === selected, 
   }); 
 }); 
 return <div className="RadioGroup">{RadioOptions}</div>; 
}; 
 
export const RadioOption = ({ value, checked, onChange, children }) => { 
 return ( 
   <div className="RadioOption"> 
     <input 
       id={value} 
       type="radio" 
       name={value} 
       value={value} 
       checked={checked} 
       onChange={(e) => { 
         onChange(e.target.value); 
       }} 
     /> 
     <label htmlFor={value}>{children}</label> 
   </div> 
 ); 
};
```

#### Explanation:

Most of the code seems pretty straightforward, except for when the legacy APIs [`React.Children`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Children) and [`React.cloneElement`](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement) (both of whom the usage is currently discouraged by React Docs themselves) are used. However, since these are the two most important functionalities of the code (and indeed the APIs that Meta intended to teach us in the course), I will go through what I believe they are doing, in an effort to help any future coursemates who might stumble upon the same piece of code, and in the end my question itself will be much clearer. To any more experienced coders who might be reading this: please, I invite you to correct any mistakes I make on my attempt at an explanation.

1. We start by creating a `RadioGroup` element whose children are various `RadioOption` elements. Since a component receives its children from its constructor, I presume that **a component's children must be created before the component itself** in order for them to be available for their injection inside of their parent component. This means that in this example, the `RadioOption` elements are created before the initialization of the `RadioGroup` element (which only makes sense, given that in the initialization of the `RadioGroup` element we already have a `children` object over which to iterate).
2. From that point, we jump over to the creation of the `RadioOption` elements in `src/Radio/index.js`. Since only the `value` attribute has been provided on their initialization in `src/App.js`, what seems to happen is that only the attributes who do not depend on either the `checked` or the `onChange` parameters for their initialization are properly initialized, for **to the properties that receive parameters that have not been provided, `undefined` is assigned**, and **React ignores all the properties to whom `undefined` is assigned.** This means that by the end of this step, each `RadioOption` element will be a `<div>` with: an `<input>` tag with the attributes `id`, `type`, `name` and `value`; and a `<label>` tag with the attribute `htmlFor`.
3. Once this is all done, we are ready to create our `RadioGroup` element. We start by creating a copy of its `children` object, which is composed of all the previously created `RadioOption` elements, applying a transformation to each of its elements, and saving the copied and subsequently modified array to a `const` called `RadioOptions`. Now, what interests me is how such transformation is done:
4. Inside of the callback for the `.map()` method, we clone each `RadioOption` element and append to it two properties which it previously did not have, namely, `onChange` and `checked`.
5. By the end of this process, the state setter function `setSelected`, that was passed into `RadioGroup` through means of its property `onChange`, has made its way from the parameter of the `RadioGroup` constructor and into the `onChange` property of each individual `RadioOption` through usage of the `React.cloneElement`. This means that the code `onChange={(e) => {onChange(e.target.value); }}` is effectively rendered `onChange={(e) => {setSelected(e.target.value); }}` on the final object.

And this is what I have been able to decipher so far.

#### Question 1:

I do not understand the following, though:

Looking online I have found many of examples like such (this one comes from the documentation itself):

```
import { cloneElement } from 'react';

// ...
const clonedElement = cloneElement(
  <Row title="Cabbage">
    Hello
  </Row>,
  { isHighlighted: true },
  'Goodbye'
);

console.log(clonedElement);
```

This is supposed to log the following result: `<Row title="Cabbage" isHighlighted={true}>Goodbye</Row>`.

As can be seen, the `isHighlighted` property was added even though there was no coded specification for how to deal with this value such as there was in our `RadioOption` component to deal with the `checked` and `onChange` values. Nevertheless, it was successfully appended to the  tag's clone.

This made me realize: **`React.cloneElement` can be used to append a property to a component independently of such a property's prior implementation.**

However, it is also the case that in the code for the radio buttons list above, **`React.cloneElement` took into account the behaviour specified in the component's body when appending the property it had been provided with.**

So where do we draw the line? How do I know exactly when it is going to behave in a way and when in another? Can anyone walk me through the inner workings of this method more in-depth?

---

#### Question 2:

Moreover, when we look at the example just above, we see that the passing of `{ isHighlighted: true }` as an argument to `React.cloneElement` was enough to create, in the final object, a property `isHighlighted` with the value `true`.

However, in our code, we need the line `checked={checked}` inside of the `<input>`tag for the code to work properly. I believe that it might be because in the documentation's example the appending was done to a simple `<Row>` tag, whilst in our code the appending takes place one level deeper than our RadioOption's `<div>`, on the `<input>` tag inside of that.

Is that correct? And at last: how could I make it so that I could mimic the working of the documentation's example code, i.e., passing everything that should be appended inside the `cloneElement()` call and not relying in passing it as an argument to the constructor of the `RadioOption` component?

---

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "*a component receives its children from its constructor*"?

Comment: "*From that point, we jump over to the creation of the `RadioOption` elements in src/Radio/index.js.*", "*`React.cloneElement` took into account the behaviour specified in the component's body*" - no, and no. I think you will need to check your understanding of the [difference between component and elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30971395/1048572) as well as the react [render behaviour](https://react.dev/learn/render-and-commit) and component lifecycle (which is not really well explained in the new docs afaics)

Comment: I see. Thank you so much, @Bergi. I will read through the resources you have linked.
:)